# How to save a node to xsl variable?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to store a custom node to a varible?

If I use this:

```
<xsl:variable name="test">
    <INFORMATION_DB_CODE_LIST>
            <INFORMATION_DB_CODE>
                <xsl:value-of select="'123'"/>
            </INFORMATION_DB_CODE>
    </INFORMATION_DB_CODE_LIST>
</xsl:variable>
```

when I get the variable value:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ext:node-set($test)"/>
```

it just returns `123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you don't need the `node-set` function, as the `$test` variable already contains a "temporary tree".  The problem is that `<xsl:value-of>` gives you the string value of its argument, which in the case of an element node means the concatenation of all its text node descendants (so in this case just the string `123`).  You probably want `copy-of` instead of `value-of`, to copy the element node itself to the output rather than just its string value.